# ArrayList String manipulation

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing a simple program to reformat source code using new line style curly brace to end of line curly brace style. I'm having trouble manipulating strings to then pass them to an arraylist.

My specific problem is when I find a line which has a new line curly brace, I then get the index of the line before, set the new line to the element in the previous index and append a `"{"`, I am having trouble removing the previous line.

I've tried doing `.remove(previousIndex)` but it did not work

Sample input:

```
public class Reformat
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Test 1");
        System.out.println("Test 2");
    }
}
```

This is my code so far:

```
public class Reform {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Pass source file to File object
        File sourceFile = new File(arg[0]);
        // Create AL of type String to hold tokens
        ArrayList<String> code = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = null;
        // Try-catch block to handle any errors while opening the file
        try {
            input = new Scanner(sourceFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String currentLine = input.nextLine();

                if (currentLine.isEmpty()) {
                    continue;
                } else if (currentLine.contains("{") && code.size() != 0) {
                    int previousIndex = code.size() - 1;
                    code.add(code.set(previousIndex, code.get(previousIndex) + "{"));
                } else {
                    code.add(currentLine);
                }
            }//end of while
            for (String line : code)
                System.out.println(line);
        }//end of finally
        input.close();
    }//end of main
}//end of class
```

Comment: Your `finally` part will run even if an exception is thrown.. I think you want to move all that processing into the `try` part and only `input.close()` in the finally

Comment: Why don't you use your IDE for formatting code?

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the code in question and was able to resolve by arranging in this manner:

```
 else if (currentLine.contains("{") && code.size() != 0) {
                int previousIndex = code.size() - 1;
                String newLine = code.set(previousIndex, code.get(previousIndex) + "{");
                code.add(previousIndex, newLine);
                code.remove(previousIndex);
```

Not 100% sure why it worked in this way and not the other attempts. I would appreciate an explanation. The worst type of solutions are the ones you don't understand.

Answer (score -1):

This is wrong:

```
code.add(code.set(previousIndex, code.get(previousIndex) + "{"));
```

It should be:

```
code.set(previousIndex, code.get(previousIndex) + "{");
```

Comment: Well it was orginialy String newLine = code.set(previousIndex, code.get(previousIndex) + "{"); code.add(newLine);

Comment: Why are you trying to grab the previous line in its unmodified form? I thought the point was to alter it to add the "{"?

Comment: Yes, and I don't understand why dont you @n0tion post a working code without File. :)

Comment: Yes, that is the point. I could not find an append method for ArrayList. So my thought process was to grab the original form, append the {, remove the original line, and append the new line with the end of line curly brace.